# Keep a frame's properties the same in Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash, properties, frames

I am making a game in Adobe Flash CS6, and all is going well except one part which I'm stuck on.

See, there is a "Levels" frame with many buttons which take you to the designated level (I guess you could say it is has the layout of the Angry Birds level page).

Now, if I go away from that frame, BEAT level 1, and return to the "Levels" frame, how do I make it so that it would show that Level 1 is complete?
I would just want, lets say, a checkmark to be visible right under that level box.

All I have that could be useful to you is this.

```
_root.Checkmark1._visible = true;
```

Sorry, I know that's not enough, but can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming :

- You are using AS2 (looking @ _root).
- Checkmark1 is the default check box component from the component library.

While writing a game in AS2 try not to use too many global properties (the ones in _root) directly. Or it might get too confusing later. Try wrapping up all the refrences to checkboxes for the levels into an array, something like :

```
_root.levelChkBoxArray = [Checkmark1,Checkmark2.....];
```

or better could be a boolean array instead of the object array, if visibility is all you need to set.

Now you could set the visibility from any frame.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand this... So what you are trying to say is that if I make an array with the checkboxes in it, that frame will not revert to it's original state when I change a frame (I hope it does)?

Comment: I just meant to say that you could use an array to keep the state of the checkboxes. While showing the checkboxes in the relevant frame, check their state in this array...